# Перевернуть строку в PHP

Tags: php, алгоритм

Как перевернуть строку? Было **Привет** - стало **тевирП**.
Стандартную функцию не предлагать - `strrev()` не работает с кодировкой utf-8.
Варианты которые сделал:

1. Использование mbstring. Проход циклом с конца строки, достаем буквы через `mb_substr()`, формируем итоговую строку.
2. Использование регулярных выражений. Выборка символов через `preg_match_all()` в массив, делаем `array_reverse()` и `implode()`.

Подскажите еще варианты алгоритмов/реализаций подобного преобразования.

Comment: strrev - поддерживает UTF

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev где об этом написано?

Comment: @u_mulder, а где написано что не поддерживает?

Comment: В мануале не написано. Собственно, ответ ниже это вариант из комментов.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strrev.php где? то, что какой то пользователь написал?

Comment: Всякие апвотеры того что `strrev` поддерживает utf-8, хоть тест напишите - https://3v4l.org/n7nI5.

Comment: `strrev` поддерживает все кодировки, потому что не работает с ними. функция инвертирует порядок байт, а уж как там уровнем выше эти байты интерпретирует клиент - проблема клиента. поэтому верно и утверждение "поддерживает utf" и любое другое типа "поддерживает <вставь любое значение>"

Comment: @u_mulder только хотел ответить, но Lexx918 дал точный ответ. Если ваша строка будет в utf-16, а лучше в 32, то никаких проблем не будет. Просто нужно понимать как работает эта функция. Как раз Let's say Pie дал точный ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function mb_strrev($text)
{
    return join('', array_reverse(preg_split('//u', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)));
}

echo mb_strrev('☆❤world');
```

Ну, и еще как вариант можно рассмотреть:

```
function mb_strrev($string)
{
    $string = strrev(mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8'));
    return mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE');
}

echo mb_strrev('☆❤world');
```

Comment: @Эдуард, спасибо, не заметил..

Comment: Спасибо, с `preg_split()` не пробовал, нужно потестировать эффективность по сравнению с `preg_match_all()`. Подождем еще немного других вариантов решения задачи.

Comment: @iapetus, дополнил ответ еще одним вариантом

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strrev.php#122953

```
function mb_strrev($str){
    $r = '';
    for ($i = mb_strlen($str); $i>=0; $i--) {
        $r .= mb_substr($str, $i, 1);
    }
    return $r;
}

echo mb_strrev("☆❤world"); // echo "dlrow❤☆"
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но эта реализация стоит первым пунктом в моем вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "football";
$exp = str_split($str);
$revers = array_reverse($exp);
$imp = implode('',$revers);
var_dump($imp);
?>
```